# How can I get one variable to equal 0 by using another variable to define that variable?

Tags: java

In Java, suppose I have two variables, `x1` and `xName`.

How can I get `x1` to equal 0 by using `xName`?

`xName`'s value is `"x1"`. How can I change `x1`'s value with `xName`?

I have my reasons for not just changing x1 to 0.

edit: To clarify, I want to use xName to define x1.
if x1 = 1 initially. I want to do this basically
xName = 0. and x1 becomes 0 because xName's value is "x1".
 I've never come across it before so 
I'm just wondering if this was possible.

Comment: so xName is the name of the variable inside the program?

Comment: no i mean like. I want to use xName to define x1.
if x1 = 1 initially. I want to do this basically
xName = 0. and x1 becomes 0 because xName's value is "x1".
you know what i mean? I've never come across it before so 
im just wondering if this was possible.

Comment: The exact syntax you are suggesting in the above edit is not possible.

Comment: alright thanks, just making sure. trying to condense the amount of coding i needed to do

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correct you want to set the variable whose name is contained in xName to 0?

If x1 is a field of a class then you can use reflection to set the value of the field. Notice that I don't handle any exceptions.

```
public class ChangeField {

    public int x1 = 5;
    public int x2 = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChangeField changeField = new ChangeField();        
        System.out.println("Before " + changeField);
        changeField.reset("x1");
        System.out.println("After " + changeField);
    }

    private void reset(String xName) throws Exception {
        getClass().getDeclaredField(xName).setInt(this, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("x1=%1$s x2=%2$s", x1, x2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection. Here's the [official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html).

Comment: Reflection is not simple, not effieient and not recommended. If it can be done another way then that would be a preference. But with a good enought reason; it is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you can change the code around, you might just want to try a Map:

```
Map<String, Integer> mappings = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
mappings.put(xName, x1);

// delegates setting the value to the Map
void setValue(String variableName, int variableValue) {
    this.mappings.put(variableName, variableValue);
}

// delegates getting the value to the Map.
void getValue(String variableName) {
    return this.mappings.get(variableName);
}
```

Obviously the delegates are not strictly necessary.